# update table by column type

Tags: mysql

I have a large MYSQL table of data with sensitive numbers. We need an outside company to make a app for us that will consume the data. We do not want to give them the real numbers. Rather i would like to fake the data. Here is what i am trying

**Sample Table**

```
Name<varChar> | col1 <int>| col2 <decimal>| coln <int>
Joe           |  1        |  2            |  3
```

I want to write a script that updates all columns that are either integers or decimals (basically anything that is numeric) by taking the current real value and multiplying it by a random number larger than `ZERO`.

Here is a sample chunk of code i have written that is on the right track.

```
UPDATE TABLE SET VALUE=VALUE*ROUND(RAND());
```

**But is missing the following:**

1) Only updates one column

2) Does not verify that the column is numeric data

can someone help with this sql script.

Comment: The distinction of "multiply" and "divide" is pointless, since a/3 is the same as a*0,3333333... Perhaps the distribution of the factor matters.

Comment: Division does not add randomness to the process: if the number by which you multiply is random, you could think of multiplying by it as if it were a division by a random reciprocal of that number.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you guys are right about the multiplication. I can simply restrict assume that Rant() <1 is division. Updating question

Comment: Don't understand your 2) - running DESCRIBE sample_table will let you know how the col is defined. And the CAST() function can be utilized to convert str to float. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598 i want to automatethe process. I understand how to do this with manual intervention.

Comment: do you want to do this purely in mysql?

Comment: What's the Java tag doing here? This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Java. I'm removing the tag for now. If there is a connection to Java, please edit the question to specify what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mysql only solution. You can query the `information_schema` table for columns by type and then construct your sql query by using variables.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE example (
    ->          id INT,
    ->          data VARCHAR(100),
    ->          id2 INT,
    ->          id3 decimal,
    ->          id4 double,
    ->          id5 float,
    ->          id6 numeric   
    ->        );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> insert into example values (1,'hello',2,3,4,5,6);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> SET @sql = NULL;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(column_name,'=ROUND(',column_name,'*RAND())'))
    -> INTO @sql
    -> FROM information_schema.columns 
    -> WHERE table_schema = 'test' -- your db name
    -> AND table_name = 'example' 
    -> AND (column_type LIKE  '%int%'
    -> OR column_type LIKE '%decimal%'
    -> OR column_type LIKE '%numeric%'
    -> OR column_type LIKE '%float%'
    -> OR column_type LIKE '%double%');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @sql1 = CONCAT("UPDATE example SET ",@sql);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> EXECUTE stmt;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from example;
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id   | data  | id2  | id3  | id4  | id5  | id6  |
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|    0 | hello |    0 |    3 |    4 |    1 |    3 |
+------+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select @sql1;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @sql1                                                                                                                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| UPDATE example SET id=ROUND(id*RAND()),id2=ROUND(id2*RAND()),id3=ROUND(id3*RAND()),id4=ROUND(id4*RAND()),id5=ROUND(id5*RAND()),id6=ROUND(id6*RAND()) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: FuzzyTree getting an error. `Query:  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql1

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

Comment: i think the problem is that i have too many columns and the  `select group_concat....` statement where `@sql` is being set is getting truncated. `Row 33 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()`

Comment: added `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` to solved the concat issue

Comment: you did it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do this with Java. You can fully automate this using system tables or `ResultSetMetaData`.

Pseudo code:

- Get the full list of user tables and columns that match numeric data types, ordered by table names. (There should be a SQL query for MySQL to fetch this info from a system table or view.)
- For each table, build and execute the update statement updating all the columns with your random multiplication.

Alternative pseudo code:

- Get the full list of user tables.
- For each table, get one row of data (doesn't matter which row as you won't iterate the `ResultSet`).
- Use the `ResultSetMetaData` object to get column names and data types.
- Build and execute the update statement updating all the columns that match numeric data types with your random multiplication.

As always, run the program against a small test database that can be reset with a database build script. It should contain a few tables with columns and data of various data types.

Answer (score 0):

if you would like to do this in just mysql use java to execute this query.

```
UPDATE table t,
(
    SELECT id,
        col1*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1 as c1,
        col2*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1 as c2,
        col3*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1 as c3
    FROM table
) as temp
SET temp.c1 = t.col1, temp.c2 = t.col2, temp.c3 = t.col3 WHERE t.id = temp.id;
```

**TWO THINGS :** **FIRST** this assumes you have a unique id for each row as all normalized tables should have this. **SECOND** your random number range can change to whatever you want it all you have to do is change `FLOOR(RAND() * 9)` to something else... FLOOR(min * max).. so make the 9 a different number to change the range. the reason why I add 1 at the end is incase you don't want the number to change to 0 then add one after the FLOOR to make it at least 1

---

**EDIT:**
to handle checking if its numeric or not then just to a simple IF comparison like so:

```
UPDATE table t,
(
    SELECT id,
        IF(col1 >=0, col1*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1, col1) as c1,
        IF(col2 >=0, col2*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1, col2) as c2,
        IF(col3 >=0, col3*FLOOR(RAND() * 9) +1, col3) as c3
    FROM table
) as temp
SET temp.c1 = t.col1, temp.c2 = t.col2, temp.c3 = t.col3 WHERE t.id = temp.id;
```